# Javascript SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some small script, but since I did it with Google help I need some advice. After putting this into Chrome console, I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    if jQuery("#colorbox").css("display", "none");) {
        jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "none");
    } 
    else {
        jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "visible");
    }
});
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: i have div with id colorbox and style="display: none"

Comment: [jshint](http://jshint.com) can help with this kind of thing.

Comment: If you get a SyntaxError, that means you have a SyntaxError, and need to take a close look at your code, and correct the invalid JavaScript.

Comment: the script is works now, but i dont see any changes on my page.
Was it correct to to use .css on colorbox id, while it has .style in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
if jQuery("#colorbox").css("display", "none");)
```

to:

```
if (jQuery("#colorbox").css("display") == 'none')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jQuery("#colorbox").css("display", "none")) {
    jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "none");
} 
else {
    jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it with the syntax errors fixed:

```
jQuery(function () {
    if (jQuery("#colorbox").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "none");
    } else {
        jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "visible");
    }
});
```

and even simpler with toggle

```
jQuery(function () {
    var isVisible = jQuery("#colorbox").is(":visible")) {
    jQuery("#close-news").toggle(!isVisible);        
});
```